# Rails find a specific entry in a scoped table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, subset

New to rails....still trying to grasp all the "methods"

Table is called Histories.

```
   @compa = History.scoped(:limit => 10,:conditions => {:name => "IBM"}, :order => "closedate ASC")
```

Now I want to find if that @compa subset of the table contains an entry where the closedate = a specific date.  I've tried all sorts of methods, but nothing seems to work.

Example:

```
if (@compa.has_value?(tmp))
```

Doesn't work.

Should I work in the subset, or go back to the table and do a new scope? How can I work in the subset...I'm missing something I'm sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you would want something like:

```
if(@compa.include?(tmp))
```

To see if @compa has the value, `tmp`.

However `@compa` contains attributes other than closedate. So you would want:

```
@compa.find{|o| o['closedate'] == tmp}
```

This will return nil if it doesn't contain that value, otherwise it will return the object that does have `closedate` equal to `tmp`.

However why not use SQL to handle this:

Since `@compa` is an ActiveRecord Relation(because you called scoped), you can query it more by doing something like:

```
@compa.where(:closedate => tmp).exists?
```

Links:

[Array#include](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000265)

[Enumerable#find](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001484)

[exists?](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#existence-of-objects)

Comment: Thanks!  The where method works great!  Can you indulge me and explain the |o| and o['closedate'] in the find?  That doesn't seem to work for me, I only get nil.